# Why my code is returning garbage value in C

Tags: arrays, c, data-structures

In the below code I want to reverse the array I created the function **arrev()** & using while loop to do it

```
#include <stdio.h>
int arrev(int arr[], int revarr[], int N)
{
    int start = 0;
    while (N > 0)
    {
        revarr[start] = arr[N];
        start++;
        N--;
    }
}
int print(int arr[], int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[10], revarr[10], N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("Input String:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }
    arrev(arr, revarr, N);
    printf("Reversed String:\n");
    print(revarr, N);
}
```

[This is my Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xP7ze.png)
I am entering the following input:
3
1
2
3
And after reversing I am getting the garbage value as output

Comment: The loop in the reversal function is wrong. Remember, in c indexes are 0..(N-1) for an array of magnitude N. You're using 1..N .You can fix this with simply moving the `N--` to be the N-ish expression in the while loop. I.e. `while (N-- > 0)`. Don't forget to *remove* the one inside the loop.

Comment: Use a debugger to single-step through the code, observe the behaviour. What indices your array are you accessing?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and look for the problem yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least this problem:

Off-by-one indexing

```
int arrev(int arr[], int revarr[], int N)
{
    int start = 0;
    while (N > 0)
    {
        // revarr[start] = arr[N];
        revarr[start] = arr[N-1];
        start++;
        N--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

arr[N] would definitely consist of garbage value.

You need to store arr[N-1] not arr[N]

**correct code  :**

```
{
    int start = 0;
    N--;
    while (N >= 0)
    {
        revarr[start] = arr[N];
        start++;
        N--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an OBO

Change to

```
while (N > 0)
{
    N--;
    revarr[start] = arr[N];
    start++;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be an _OBOE_? :) Off by one error.

Comment: @Lundin Now you're mixing it up with https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oboe ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to indexing issue, In C array starts with 0 goes till N-1.

In `arrev()` you need to decrement N before assigning to reverse array. this code will work

```
int arrev(int arr[], int revarr[], int N)
{
    int start = 0;
 
    while (N > 0)
    { 
        N--;
        printf(" rev array %d\n", revarr[start]);

        printf(" init array %d\n", arr[N]);
       
        revarr[start] = arr[N];
        start++;
        // printf(revarr[start])
      
    }
   }
```

As a part of best practice, If you're using int as return type, you should use `return 0` or use `void` as return type.

Also if you want to reverse the array, there is an in-place mechanism which can be achieved.

```
void arrev(int arr[], int start, int end)
{
 //start = 0
// end = sizeof(arr) - 1

    int temp;
    while (start < end)
    {
        temp = arr[start];  
        arr[start] = arr[end];
        arr[end] = temp;
        start++;
        end--;
    }  
}
```